# I want to output a list of every Case_Number with Code 1 that has a higher UniqueID value than its Code 2 counterpart's UniqueID value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks something like this:

```
    Case_Number  |  Code  |  UniqueID
        a             1       1372
        a             2       1352
        a             3       1325
        b             1       1642
        b             2       1651
        b             3       1623
        c             1       1743
        c             2       1739
        c             3       1720
       ...           ...        ...
```

From this database I want to output a list of every Case_Number where the UniqueID value of Code 1 is higher than the UniqueID value of Code 2 (But ignoring the UniqueID value of Code 2, or any other Code x that might be in the table). Meaning that if the UniqueID value of Code 2 is higher than Code 1, which is the case with Case_Number b in the example above, it should not show up in the list.

So, querying the above table would result in this:

```
    Case_Number  |  Code  |  UniqueID
        a             1       1372
        c             1       1743
```

Comment: What have  you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.code = 1 and
      t.uniqueid > (select max(t2.uniqueid)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.case_number = t.case_number and t2.code = 2
                   );
```

The `max()` in the subquery is simply to handle the case where there is more than one matching value.

Answer (score 0):

The query below gives you the expected result

```
CREATE TABLE CaseTab
(Case_Number VARCHAR(10),
 Code        INT,  
 UniqueID    INT);

INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('a',             1,       1372);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('a',             2,       1352);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('a',             3,       1325);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('b',             1,       1642);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('b',             2,       1651);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('b',             3,       1623);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('c',             1,       1743);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('c',             2,       1739);
INSERT INTO CaseTab VALUES ('c',             3,       1720);

WITH v_code_gt_1 AS
(SELECT Case_Number, MAX(UniqueID) AS UniqueID
   FROM CaseTab
  WHERE Code > 1
  GROUP BY Case_Number)
SELECT c1.Case_Number, c1.UniqueID
  FROM CaseTab c1 JOIN
       v_code_gt_1 c2
       ON (c1.Case_Number = c2.Case_Number)
 WHERE c1.UniqueID > c2.UniqueID
   AND c1.Code = 1;
```

Basically the query gets the max UniqueID for all cases where code is greater than 1 and compares against the Unique ID for Code 1.

You haven't stated whether there can be cases with code = 1, but no other codes. If so, use LEFT JOIN as below.

```
WITH v_code_gt_1 AS
(SELECT Case_Number, MAX(UniqueID) AS UniqueID
   FROM CaseTab
  WHERE Code > 1
  GROUP BY Case_Number)
SELECT c1.Case_Number, c1.UniqueID
  FROM CaseTab c1 LEFT JOIN
       v_code_gt_1 c2
       ON (c1.Case_Number = c2.Case_Number)
 WHERE c1.UniqueID > ISNULL(c2.UniqueID, 0)
   AND c1.Code = 1;
```